# VSX - How to save options page data

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsx

I've create a Custom Options Page with a few TextBoxes, ComboBoxes etc etc.

I have 2 questions though:

- I can see that the values I input in the fields remain there if I close/reopen the Options Windows but that doesnt happen if I close VS and reopen. How can I make sure the data is stored "for real?"
- How can I access these values from a Action Menu? For instance, I have a menu option Tools > MyButton that will take the values from the options and do some stuff.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The real issue is that where the fields were saved if you re-open your VS, for example, if any of the value was saved to your default VS settings, if you re-open it, it would still remember the value.

Comment: I didn't change anything on that bit. So, if they are saved somewhere before been loaded in VS (without closing the instance) I don't know where it is.

Comment: Maybe you could get useful information from these two cases:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5ea00b1f-f189-4f7d-bf71-3b791cb98b10/automatically-saveload-options-in-custom-dialogpage?forum=vsx&forum=vsx and https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/65e381a2-dc3b-4c02-bfee-33191f1a7d00/save-the-textbox-value-into-suo-file?forum=vsx, they try to save the value to the suo file or others.